# Copmarision between Arraylist and Hashset for insertion, deletion, search

Tags: arraylist, hashset

insertion, search ,deletion in HashSet and ArrayList- which is faster.

I think search in Arraylist is faster compared to Hashset
and deletion is faster in Hashset.
insertion is faster in ArrayList.
Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

A HashSet and an ArrayList are completely different data types. You should read a bit about the Java Collections Framework: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework

and BTW: A HashSet is *much* faster at searching than an ArrayList, as that's its intended purpose. Deletions and Insertions are also faster in a HashSet (whose elements are unsorted), as an ArrayList has to shift all objects following the deleted/inserted object by one (except if adding to/removing from the end of the list of course).